# Getting a "stderr: Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again Exception in thread "main" while running java

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, child-process

I have a `Java` and `nodeJS` project where the input is sent to the backend using the below code:

```
app.post('/my-button', function (req, res) {
  console.log('POST request received');
  const input = decodeURIComponent(req.body.inputText);
  console.log(input); // For debugging purposes
  
  const scriptPath = path.join(__dirname, '/Backend/Main.java');
  const script = spawn('java', [scriptPath, input]);

  let output = '';
```

And it is collected at the backend as `args` for the main method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String sql_input=args[0];
    List<String> processed_statements = converter(sql_input);
```

Once I start the server and give and input the server crashes and give the following error.

[image: error msg]

How do I solve this issue as I have Java installed on my system.

[image: files structure if that helps]

I tried a different way of running java.

```
const javaPath = 'java'; // Assuming 'java' is in the system's PATH
const classPath = path.join(__dirname, '/Backend/'); // Path to the Backend folder
console.log(classPath);
const className = 'Main'; // The Java class containing the main method
console.log(className);
const javaProcess = spawn(javaPath, ['-cp', classPath, className], {
    stdio: 'pipe', // Pipe to stdin and stdout
});
```

But here also I get an error as below.

```
stderr: Error: Could not find or load main class Main.java
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Main.java
```

Comment: app2.js was created after getting error with the second input idea.